# How can i override the exactly equal function for a specific string in Python?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, equality

I am borderline new to python

I want to override the == function, in one special case.
namely, I want to "trick" python into thinking that a given string is equal to any other string I compare it to
say x = "potato",
when comparing any string to x I want it to return True. 
x == "MANGO" and x == "Tomato" will be True
but of course "MANGO" == "Tomato" will still be false

I wish i didn't have to use strings, but it is necessary.

If this is not something that can be done, then never mind of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make a class inheriting from str and overriding **eq**

```
class equalToAllStrings(str):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return type(other) is str
x = equalToAllStrings("a")
x == 'b'
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks so much.